# Clicking an Image only once with an input listener

Tags: java, image, loops, break

Hello I am working on a hangman game and almost finished. My last problem is making my virtual keyboard only clickable once. I either break the loop after if checks the letter true or false and that works but it only returns one letter even if the word has to of the same letters. or leave the loop open and it returns 4 - 5 tries depending on how many times the mouse clicked from on click if u know what i mean. can i make the Inputlistner only register one click??.. here is the image and its list

```
    a = new Image(new Texture("Sprites/Keyboard/a.png"));
    a.addListener(new InputListener(){
        @Override
        public boolean touchDown(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
            apressed = true;
            return true;

        }

        @Override
        public void touchUp(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
            apressed = false;
        }

    });
```

and then here is the call method in my playstate... I tried to return a false boolean after the loop but still it registers too many clicks before ending the loop...

```
     if (tries < 100) {

        if (keyboard.apressed && abpressed == true) {
            for (int i = 0; i < randomWordtoGuess.length; i++) {
                if (a == randomWordtoGuess[i] ) {
                    playerGuess[i] = a;
                    currentWord = new String(playerGuess);
                    keyboard.a.setColor(0, 1, 0, 1);
                    abpressed = false;

                }

                if (a != randomWordtoGuess[i]) {
                    keyboard.a.setColor(1, 0, 0, 1);
                    tries++;
                    System.out.print(tries);
                    abpressed = false;
                }
                else{

                }
                // if i place a break; here it solves the problem 
                // but doesnt return more than one letter in the word.. 
                // for example Concrete it will only show first C.
            }

        }
```

}

another way to solve the problem is to just add 1 to the int "tries" instead of tries++.. but i think that cant be done??

Answer (score 0):

You can make a new boolean that will check if the keyboard has been clicked yet. Lets say we declare a global boolean `keyClicked`. Then, just add this to your `InputListener`:

```
a.addListener(new InputListener(){    
    @Override
    public boolean touchDown(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
        if (!keyClicked) {
            apressed = true;
            keyClicked = true;
            return true;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void touchUp(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
        if (!keyClicked) {
            apressed = false;
            keyClicked = true;
        }
    }

});
```

Comment: doesnt work :(.. but i understand what ur trying to do.. also it slowed the app down